# Find out which Facebook fan has most friends among the fan network

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am looking to build an application that will basically perform the following query : It will pull the profileID of the Facebook fan who has most friends among the Facebook Page fans.

I looked through StackOverflow and realize that the Facebook API may not have a way to generate the total list of Facebook fans. But since it is possible to generate the list of top 500 fans (or at least that is what I learnt from one response), is my requirement feasible with Facebook's API offerings?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can not get information about a user usign the API unless you have a user specific key (i.e. the user given permission to facebook app)

Obviously if they have the profile publically accessable then you could just scrap the html